# Using algebra to solve a graph problem

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I’m reading a textbook about graph theory and its application and suddenly I’m facing some problems understanding a part which needs algebra background.
I’m gonna skip the graph related part ;
The only think that I should mention is if $xy=yx$ then $x$ and $y$ are adjacent in the graph.

The example is $S=\{(1),(1\ 2),(1\ 3),(2\ 3),(1\ 2\ 3),(1\ 3\ 2)\}$
So I have to see if $(1\ 3)(2\ 3)=(2\ 3)(1\ 3)$
The book’s answer is $(1\ 3)(2\ 3)=(1\ 3\ 2)$
And $(2\ 3)(1\ 3)=(1\ 2\ 3)$
I have no idea how it is calculated.

I would appreciate if you even link somthing for me to help me figure this out cause as I said I have no algebra background.

Comment: What kind of objects do these parenthesized numbers denote?

Comment: Permutation......? @Berci

Comment: Yes, sure. I wanted to ask it from @Negar. Next question would be what is the operation for them denoted by juxtaposition.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This $S$ is the group of all bijection maps on the set $\{1,2,3\}$. Where $(13)$ is the map that sends: $1\mapsto 3, 2\mapsto2, 3\mapsto1 $.

Then $(23)$ is the map that sends: $1\mapsto 1, 2\mapsto3, 3\mapsto2 $.

Then $(123)$ is the map that sends: $1\mapsto 2, 2\mapsto3, 3\mapsto1 $.

$(1)$ is the identity map.

I hope now you will get how the mappings are written.

Comment: Thank you but i still dont know how to write composition of two permutations. How (1 2 3)(1 2)=(1 3)?

Comment: Write the map $f=(123)$ and $g=(12)$ then find the mapping composition $f\circ g$. Then verify $f\circ g$ sends: $1\mapsto3, 2\mapsto2, 3\mapsto1$. So $f\circ g=(123)(12)=(13)$.

Answer (score 1):

define ab as a connection between a,b with respect to "adjacent in the graph"  so
$$1\longleftrightarrow3\equiv3\longleftrightarrow1\\xy =yx\\
(13)(23)=(1\longleftrightarrow3)(2\longleftrightarrow3)=\\(1\longleftrightarrow3)(3\longleftrightarrow2)\\(1\longleftrightarrow\underbrace{3 \space \space\space 3}\longleftrightarrow2)\\(13)(23)=(12)(32)=(132)$$

Comment: Thank you . But how (1 2 3)(1 2)=(1 3) ? I used your method and I don’t get the final answer yet

Comment: And i get that (1 3 2)is equal to (2 1 3)or (3 2 1) but how in the final line you conclude (13)(23)=(12)(32)? Isn’t (12)(32)=(1 2 3)?